# SQL How to Update by INNER JOIN -

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, alias

Please help me figure this out since I tried everything from this forum but still haven't found a solution.

Well, I have two tables:

- prices
- manufacturers

I want to change the values of two fields that are both in table prices. 
And I will just give specific values to those.

The fields are:

- prices.override (in which I want to give the value 0) and
- prices.product_discount_id (in which I want to give the value 66)

***BUT I want to change the fields ONLY FOR the manufacturer with ID 31.***

So, I first check that an INNER JOIN works fine.

```
SELECT manufacturers.manufacturer_id,
prices.product_id,
prices.product_price,
prices.override,
prices.product_discount_id
FROM manufacturers
INNER prices
ON manufacturers.product_id=prices.product_id
AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31;
```

---

But when I try to update the two fields, I do not know how to make that work.
For example, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE prices
SET prices.override=1
FROM
INNER JOIN prices
ON manufacturers.product_id=prices.product_id
AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31;
```

I also tried this:

```
UPDATE prices
SET prices.override=1, 
INNER JOIN manufacturers 
ON prices.virtuemart_product_id = manufacturers.virtuemart_product_id 
AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31;
```

What did i do wrong? Usually the error message I get is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM jos_virtuemart_product_prices prices INNER JOIN jos_virtuemart_product_man' at line 3

I read something for alias but still no result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well formatted question , +1 .

Comment: Poorly constructed question. -1

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

You have a few syntax problems , MySQL `UPDATE..JOIN` syntax is :

```
UPDATE T
JOIN t2 ON()
SET ..
WHERE ..
```

Secondly, you had an unnecessary comma after the `SET prices.override=1`, so:

```
UPDATE prices
INNER JOIN manufacturers 
ON prices.virtuemart_product_id = manufacturers.virtuemart_product_id 
    AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31
SET prices.override=1
```

Comment: Thanks sagi. Your suggestion worked just fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using SQL Server for mysql above is fine:

```
UPDATE p SET p.override=1
FROM prices p 
INNER JOIN manufacturers ON 
     p.virtuemart_product_id =manufacturers.virtuemart_product_id 
    AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31;
```

Comment: He specificly said he is using `MySQL` , the question is tagged MySQL , and the error is MySQL error. Also, nor his and your solution are fine for MySQL.

Comment: Sorry for saying that it was not mentioned before, you can check the edit log. Yes it was my fault of not asking DBMS before answering. Agreed

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax in MySQL:

```
UPDATE prices p JOIN
       manufacturers m
       USING (product_id)
    SET p.override=1
WHERE m.manufacturer_id = 31;
```

Note the use of table aliases.  These make a query easier to write and to read.

The syntax that you are using is appropriate for SQL Server.

Comment: I believe `using` may be confusing to new programmer's before they learn the standard syntaxes..

Comment: @sagi . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "standard" syntax, because `USING` and `ON` are both ANSI standard constructs.

Comment: I know `USING` is ANSI , I mean almost none of the join tutorials are introducing `USING` to the programmers unless they specifically search for it

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE prices  
SET prices.override=1  
FROM manufacturers  
INNER JOIN prices  
ON manufacturers.product_id=prices.product_id  
AND manufacturers.manufacturer_id=31;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the `UPDATE` with `JOIN` syntax is different, the `SET` operator should comes after the `JOIN` statement.

The correct `UPDATE` query is

```
UPDATE prices P
INNER JOIN manufacturers M ON P.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id 
                             AND M.manufacturer_id = 31;
SET P.override = 1;
```